# Why doesn't sortBy take (a -> a -> Bool)?

Tags: sorting, haskell

The Haskell `sortBy` function takes `(a -> a -> Ordering)` as its first argument. Can anyone educate me as to what the reasoning is there? My background is entirely in languages that have a similar function take `(a -> a -> Bool)` instead, so having to write one that returns `LT`/`GT` was a bit confusing.

Is this the standard way of doing it in statically typed/pure functional languages? Is this peculiar to ML-descended languages? Is there some fundamental advantage to it that I'm not seeing, or some hidden *dis*advantage to using booleans instead?

---

Summarizing:

- An `Ordering` is not `GT | LT`, it's actually `GT | EQ | LT` (apparently `GHC` doesn't make use of this under the hood for the purposes of sorting, but still)
- Returning a trichotomic value more closely models the possible outcomes of a comparison of two elements
- In certain cases, using `Ordering` rather than a `Bool` will save a comparison
- Using an `Ordering` makes it easier to implement stable sorts
- Using an `Ordering` makes it clear to readers that a comparison between two elements is being done (a boolean doesn't inherently carry this meaning, though I get the feeling many readers will assume it)

I'm tentatively accepting Carl's answer, and posting the above summary since no single answer has hit all the points as of this edit.

Comment: How do you use `Bool` to represent `Ordering`? `Bool` has two values, `Ordering` has three.

Comment: @AbhinavSarkar: You can sort entirely by checking to see if one value is less than the other.

Comment: @AbhinavSarkar: see `qsort` (C) or `std::sort` (C++).

Comment: I guess if he wants his version of `sortBy` to be stable he'll have to do two compares to determine equality.  For example, assume his `a -> a -> Bool` is semantically a "less than" operation.  If `lt a b --> false` and `lt b a --> false` then he can assume equality.  Obviously this is less convenient and can have inconsistencies, such as if `lt a b = lt b a = True`.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson: `EQ` (equal) is an acceptable value for `Ordering` in Haskell.

Comment: @AbhinavSarkar: My mistake, `qsort` takes a 3-valued comparison function, just like Haskell's `sortBy`; but `std::sort` takes a Boolean-valued one.

Comment: @mipadi Exactly my point! Using Boolean's inequality comparisons makes equality testing harder.

Comment: Note that in addition to being more informative than a single boolean comparison function (which is already a big win), having `compare` can potentially be faster than just having, say, `(<=)`.  In the latter case, we'd have to write `x < y = x <= y && x /= y`, and similarly for the other comparison functions, which could be expensive and is redundant to boot.  Using `compare`, we can compute all the information at once, which lets us write `x < y = compare x y == LT`, `x <= y = compare x y /= GT`, etc.

Comment: Using a trichotomy has a long and venerable history.  The original FORTRAN only had an IF statement that was a trichotomy, i.e., it took a value and jumped to three different labels depending on if the value was less, equal, or greater than 0.  Using a function with three values rather than two requires fewer comparisons when sorting (if the sorting takes advantage of it).

Comment: @n.m.: `std::sort` is actually more like `Data.List.sort`, not `sortBy`: it uses by default (through `std::less`) any `operator<` that happens to be defined for the type you're working with, like `sort` uses an `Ord` instance. Which is nice because that's just one necessary definition with very obvious meaning. The ability to replace `std::less` with a custom comparison function object is just the simplest way to achieve `sortBy` behaviour using the same function template, but if it was necessary to use such an object _always_ I'm sure it would also be a trichotomy in C++, like in C's `qsort`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: there are two `std::sort` overloaded functions. One uses whatever comparison is the default, like `Data.List.sort`; the other takes a comparator, like `sortBy`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think [Boolean Blindness](http://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/boolean-blindness/) is the main reason. `Bool` is a type with no domain semantics. Its semantics in the case of a function like `sortBy` come entirely from convention, not from the domain the function is operating on.

This adds one level of indirection to the mental process involved in writing a comparison function.  Instead of just saying "the three values I can return are less than, equal, or greater", the semantic building blocks of ordering, you say "I want to return less than, so I must convert it to a boolean." There's an extra mental conversion step that's always present. Even if you are well-versed in the convention, it still slows you down a bit. And if you're not well-versed in the convention, you are slowed down quite a bit by having to check to see what it is.

The fact that it's 3-valued instead of 2-valued means you don't need to be quite as careful in your sort implementation to get stability, either - but that's a minor implementation detail. It's not nearly as important as actually having your values have meanings.  (Also, `Bool` is no more efficient than `Ordering`. It's not a primitive in Haskell. They're both algebraic data types defined in libraries.)

Answer (score 20):

When you sort things, you put them in order; there's not a "truth" value to determine.

More to the point, what would "true" mean? That the first argument is less than the second? Greater than? Now you're overriding "true" to really mean "less than" (or "greater than", depending on how you choose to implement the function). And what if they're equal?

So why not cut out the middle man, so to speak, and return what you *really* mean?

Comment: Right. Haskell is just being explicit instead of riding on boolean.

Comment: "Why not cut out the middle man..." I don't know. Why not? That was pretty much my question. As I noted, Haskell is the first language I've used that expresses ordering this way, so I'm wondering what the rationale is, and why a chunk of the world seems to be doing it differently. I'm perfectly open to the possibility that this is actually The Right Way©™, but I wanted to know why that was.

Comment: An ordered set is one equipped with a single reflexive, antisymmetric, transitive relation called `less-or-equal-than`; relations are naturally represented by Boolean-valued functions.

Comment: @Inaimathi: In Haskell, declaring data types like `Ordering` that fit your problem neatly is both easy and cheap. This is not the case in all other languages, so you see a lot of sticking the cube in the round hole. Having information lost like this (representing `LT`, `GT`, `EQ` as a `Bool`) is unnecessary in Haskell, so we don't. Furthermore, a `Bool` is extremely context sensitive. An `Ordering` is not.

Answer (score 11):

There's no reason it couldn't. If you look at the [ghc implementation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/Data-List.html#sortBy), it only checks whether the result is `GT` or not. The Haskell Report version of the code uses `insertBy`, which likewise only checks for `GT` or not. You could write the following and use it without any problem:

```
sortByBool :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
sortByBool lte = sortBy (\x y -> if lte x y then LT else GT)

sort' :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
sort' = sortByBool (<=)
```

Some sorts could conceivably perform optimizations by knowing when elements are `EQ`, but the implementations currently used do not need this information.

Answer (score 6):

I think there were two separate design decisions:
1) Creating the `Ordering` type
2) Choosing for `sortBy` to return an `Ordering`value

The `Ordering` type is useful for more than just `sortBy` - for example, `compare` is the "centerpiece" of the `Ord` typeclass. Its type is `:: Ord a => a -> a -> Ordering`. Given two values, then, you can find out whether they're less than, greater than, or equal -- with any other comparison function (`(<)`, `(<=)`, `(>)`, `(>=)`), you can only rule out one of those three possibilities.

Here's a simple example where `Ordering` (at least in my opinion) makes a function's intent a little clearer:

```
f a b = 
  case compare a b of
    GT -> {- something -}
    LT -> {- something -}
    EQ -> {- something -}
```

Once you've decided to create the `Ordering` type, then I think it's natural to use it in places where that's the information you're truly looking for (like `sortBy`), instead of using `Bool` as a sort of workaround.

Answer (score 6):

Three valued `Ordering` is needed to **save comparisons** in cases where we do need to distinguish the `EQ` case. In duplicates-preserving `sort` or `merge`, we ignore the `EQ` case, so a ***predicate*** with *less-then-or-equal* semantics is perfectly acceptable. But not in case of `union` or `nubSort` where we do want to distinguish the *three* outcomes of comparison.

```
mergeBy lte (x:xs) (y:ys)
    | lte y x   = y : mergeBy lte (x:xs) ys
    | otherwise = x : mergeBy lte xs (y:ys)

union (x:xs) (y:ys) = case compare x y of 
    LT -> x : union  xs (y:ys) 
    EQ -> x : union  xs    ys 
    GT -> y : union (x:xs) ys
```

Writing the latter one with *lte* predicate is unnatural.